# What is meant by tridiagonal linear equation system?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations, numerical-linear-algebra, tridiagonal-matrices

I have to implement the SOR (Successive Over-Relaxation) method, using sparse matrices, to find the solution vector of these linear equations systems (for quite huge matrices):

[image: linear equations system]

What does that tridiag(-1,3,-1) or tridiag(1,2,1) mean? For the 1st example, what are the -1, 3 and -1? For the 2nd, what does the 1, 2 and 1 mean? Is it a matrix with a diagonal of (-1,3,1) or what could that be?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A tridiagonal $(a,b,c)$ is a matrix with upper diagonal terms $a$ and the diagonal terms $b$ and lower diagonal terms $c$

Answer (score 0):

A tridiagonal matrix $(a,b,c)$ very probably denotes a matrix with $b$s on the diagonal,$a$s on the first underdiagonal,  $c$ on the first overdiagonal and $0$ everywhere else, like this:
$$\begin{pmatrix}
b&c&0&\dots &0&0&0 \\
a&b&c&\dots&0 &0&0\\
0&a&b&\ddots&0&0 &0\\[-1ex]
\vdots&\ddots&\ddots&\ddots&\ddots&\ddots&\vdots \\[-3ex]
0&0&0&\ddots&b&c&0 \\
0&0&0&\dots&a&b&c \\
0&0&0&\dots&0&a&b
\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But the matrix you've posted isn't what you described with text before: "'s on the diagonal,'s on the first underdiagonal, 's on the first overdiagonal and 0 everywhere else". What should I take as answer, the text or the matrix posted (the one posted says that a's are on the diagonal, b's on the underdiagonal and c's on the upperdiagonal)?

Comment: @ZelelB In your case, the triples $(-1,3,-1)$ and $(1,2,1)$ are symmetric so it's more likely that the $3$ and $2$ (respectively) are intended to go on the diagonal.

Comment: @MishaLavrov Thanks, it makes sense! And same as what Mohammad Riazi said above. However, Bernard text and posted matrix are not concordant.. Just to be sure..

Comment: Oh! yes. I messed up typing. I'll fix it within seconds.